# How to make labels in AGOL look exactly the same as they do in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, fme-form

I recently prepared a very good looking map with labels in ArcGIS Pro (v3.2.1) and published it in AGOL. Now in AGOL labels are not looking the same way as they do in ArcGIS Pro!

How can I export my map from ArcGIS Pro in AGOL as WebMap without loosing label placing properties?

this is how my labels look in the ArcGIS Pro:

[image]

and this is how my labels look on AGOL:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since ArcGIS Pro has a full set of label setting controls it is easier to create good looking labels.   Unfortunately AGOL has nowhere near the same type of control so you will have difficulty getting labels that look the same. (i.e. Can't Rotate labels)  https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-labels-mv.htm

On solution I have found for my base labels has been to create an ESRI Vector Tile layer with labels.  These vector tiles honor many of the rules and formatting in ArcGIS Pro including rotation. Unfortunately this creates another layer that a user has to turn on or off.
[https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/map-authoring/labeling-in-vector-tiles.htm#:~:text=For%20vector%20tiles%2C%20clients%20place,conflicts%20and%20minimize%20dropped%20labels](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/map-authoring/labeling-in-vector-tiles.htm#:%7E:text=For%20vector%20tiles%2C%20clients%20place,conflicts%20and%20minimize%20dropped%20labels)